# How do you handle files in a django test

Tags: django, testing

I have a model that has a file field and I've been more or less testing the model like so:

```
def test_importing_file_and_processing(self):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,
                             'myapp/tests/reports/test_input_file')
    report = IngestedFile(
        filename='test_file'
    )
    report.document.save('test_file', File(open(file_path)))
    report.save()
    report.do_stuff()
    self.assertStuf....
```

Is there a "better" way to test the file? The way I'm testing things does look a little hacky.

Comment: What is wrong with your current method? What do you mean by 'hacky'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tempfile** module

```
import tempfile

tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf')

with open(tmp_file.name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('test_content')

report.document = tmp_file
```

or you can create isolated function for that

```
def generate_test_file(file_format='.pdf'):

    tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=file_format)

    with open(tmp_file.name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('test_content')

    return tmp_file
```